# Error 404 for POST Request using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, afnetworking

I'm getting this error and I can't figure out why :/

```
2015-02-19 10:53:45.005 Agendize[4233:60b] Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: not found (404)" UserInfo=0x1782e4980 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x17022e3c0> { URL: https://mylink } { status code: 404, headers {
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Length" = 104;
Date = "Thu, 19 Feb 2015 16:12:32 GMT";
Server = "nginx/1.1.19";
```

Here is my xcode request :

```
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parametersDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData  timeoutInterval:10];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"Basic: someValue" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[request setValue: @"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
```

Help please !!!

Comment: so...your error is telling you your request didn't find whatever it was you were looking for.  with the placeholder data you provide, there's no way to determine what the problem is. use a REST client to test your end points and requests. check out [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSError *error=nil;
NSString *url = @"Your URL to post data";
NSData *jsonRequestDict= [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:userDict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *jsonCommand=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonRequestDict encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"***jsonCommand***%@",jsonCommand);

NSDictionary *params =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:jsonCommand,@"requestParam", nil];
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];  //AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];

[manager POST:url parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSError *error=nil;
    NSString *responseStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Request Successful, response '%@'", responseStr);
    NSMutableDictionary *jsonResponseDict= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Response Dictionary:: %@",jsonResponseDict);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?